# Mascara para CPF e Data usando <p:keyboard> Primafaces

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, primefaces-5.2

Procurei em vários site sobre este assunto mais não encontrei nada que resolvesse meu problema. Vamos lá, eu tenho dois campos um de CPF e outro de Data de Nascimento ambos utilizando o componente "keyboard" do Primafaces, portanto gostaria de saber se tem como adicionar mascaras a estes campos sem uso de Jquery.

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml

Comment: Bom dia @JcSaint, o problema é que estou usando  <p:keyboard> e não estou conseguindo fazer a mascará para os campos descritos acima. Esta solução não resolve o meu problema, mesmo assim agradeço o tempo para poder me ajudar. Obrigado.

Comment: Cara provavelmente você não irá conseguir fazer o que deseja sem o uso de javascript não, pois esse componente do primefaces não tem um atributo para setar máscara.

Comment: Boa tarde @José Assis, consegui resolver aqui, mas realmente tive que utilizar JQuery buscando o id do componente. Mas muito obrigado pela resposta.